# Screenshot result in black image (Winapi)

Tags: c++, winapi, screenshot

i am trying to take a screenshot of a region on the screen using a function:

```
void ScreenShot(POINT leftTop, POINT rightBottom) {
    int width = abs(rightBottom.x - leftTop.x);
    int height = abs(rightBottom.y - leftTop.y);

    cout << "w: " << endl << width << endl << "h: " << endl << height << endl;
    // copy screen to bitmap
    HDC     hScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC     hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, width, height);
    HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
    BOOL    bRet = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, width, height, hScreen, leftTop.x, leftTop.y, SRCCOPY);

    // save bitmap to clipboard
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
    CloseClipboard();

    // clean up
    SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hScreen);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```

But when pasting the contents of the clipboard into for example paint it results in a black image. The image has the correct dimensions passed as parameters.. I cant figure out what is wrong here.

EDIT: The black image was just the result of the screenshots dimensions being glitchy, it took a screenshot of a black part of my screen only. Currently trying to figure out what variables i am using wrong.

EDIT 2: I found the issue, Something to to with the application window i try to screenshot was scaled up. So that the rect i got from it was actually smaller than the application window itself. The screenshot using that rect did therefore not represent the whole application window.

Comment: Typo? `abs(topLeft.y - topLeft.y)`

Comment: You don't check for errors. Why not?

Comment: Oh yeah i found the issue it was a typo

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it compiled correctly it was just a typo

Comment: You don't check for errors. At runtime. Why not? Read the documentation again and concentrate on how errors are signaled.

Comment: Hmm i fixed the typo and think the variables are correct i think, but the screenshot is not at the correct place...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why do you assume i dont check for errors? That is not very nice.

Comment: The code does not check for errors when calling API functions. No assumptions made by me, I'm just describing what is in the question. Ignore me if you prefer.